# Paragraph formulated in line with a contact

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://dl.dg-site.com/contact-2/

This is code HTML for my paragraph:

```
<p id="text_contact2">00 257 777 61263<br>00 257 712 084 64</p>
```

I want this paragraph to be in line placed as in the picture below.

http://i58.tinypic.com/2m60dhz.png

I tried to do this but not working

```
#text_contact2{display:inline-block;}
```

Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry but the screenshot doesn't help.

Comment: Your form already takes up the whole width, since it is `display:block` and has no width assigned to it.

Comment: do you need more information?what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forms are display: block; meaning they take up all the space available in the parent div. So you need to change the form divs to display: inline-block; CSS can be frustrating especially when you don't know what it's doing. Try right clicking in Chrome and inspecting the elements. That's what I did on your website and saw the problem instantly. I'll list the exact css to help you.

```css
form.content-form.commentsblock div{display: inline-block;}
```